# Create labels from array

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, label

I want to create labels based on an array, but i always get only one label.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count);
    Label[] lblHDDName = new Label[hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        lblHDDName[i] = new Label();
        lblHDDName[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        lblHDDName[i].Text = "Test";
        groupBoxHDD.Controls.Add(lblHDDName[i]);

        y += 10;
    }
}
```

Debugging

```
Debug.WriteLine(hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count);
```

Shows two items in the array.

The problem is that in the GroupBox there is only one label instead of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `y` variable is defined in the for loop, not outside. Therefore, for each execution of the loop, you initialize it to `10` and use it in your `System.Drawing.Point`. If you want to keep track of the increment done at the end of the loop, you must declare and initialize `y` before the for loop.

```
int y = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
   // use y
   ...

   // increment it
   y += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting y back to 10 at the start of each iteration of the loop.

move the declaration of x and y outside of the loop.

this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    ....
```

should be:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
{    
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you're creating all the right labels - but they've all got the same position of (10, 10). If you want to see more than one of them, you'll need to put them in difference places :) Either declare `y` outside the loop, or simply use:

```
lblHDDName[i].Location = new Point(10, i * 10 + 10);
```

Rather than hard-coding the positions, you may want to look into an auto-arranging control of some description.

Also, it looks like you don't really need the array of labels at all - you're not using them afterwards. For example, you could have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
    {
        // Assuming you're using C# 3 or higher
        Label label = new Label {
            Location = new Point(10, i * 10 + 1),
            Text = "test"
        };
        groupBoxHDD.Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

or even:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
    {
        groupBoxHDD.Controls.Add(new Label {
            Location = new Point(10, i * 10 + 1),
            Text = "test"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move the

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
```

out of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you have is that the `x` and `y` declarations are inside the loop so `y` will always be *10* even though you add 10 to it in the end of the loop. The labels will always be in the same position. To fix this move `int y = 10` outside of the for loop. You should move  `int x = 10` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

move

```
int x=10;
int y=10;
```

outside the loop

and increment y by 30

if( you want the labels to align themselves to their starting point

```
int x=10;
```

can remain inside the loop

```
int x = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < hardrive.GetHardDriveName.Count; i++)
    {

        int y = 10;

        lblHDDName[i] = new Label();
        lblHDDName[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        lblHDDName[i].Text = "Test";
        groupBoxHDD.Controls.Add(lblHDDName[i]);

        y += 30;
    }
```