# How to fetch data from database into a label (lambda or linq)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm designing an online test system. I want to read 20 questions from the database and display the labels? (by EF)

```
Model.db_ExamOnlineEntities dbobj = new Model.db_ExamOnlineEntities();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.Table_Question qs = new Model.Table_Question();

    var query = dbobj.Table_Question.Find(qs.qtext);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = query.ToString();
    }
}
```

How to create 20 labels?

Comment: 20 question is random or just 20 first question?

Comment: You should Take(20) in method linq.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004323/8024897

Comment: @ZiggZagg the post really has to do nothing with the op question

Comment: @BarrJ I too seems the op is asking how to create 20 labels since the current logic op has will just overwrite the .Text in label1 and which ever is the last string will go to that label.

Answer (score 2):

I'm speculating you're using ASP.NET (aspx), in this case I would recommend for you to use ListView/Repeater rather than looping and creating controls on the fly.

See sample usage [here.](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui)

*EDIT: ZiggZagg's [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004323/8024897) for creating controls on the fly may work too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Take(int count)`:

```
Model.db_ExamOnlineEntities dbobj = new Model.db_ExamOnlineEntities();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.Table_Question qs = new Model.Table_Question();

    var query = dbobj.Table_Question.Find(qs.qtext).Take(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = query.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `Take(int count)` will fetch you the given number of elements according to your query, meaning that if you use for example:

```
var query = (from foo in bar).Take(100)
```

Will return you the top 100 records of foo row from bar table,

Comment: of course OP doesn't want to display all 20 questions in label1